# Why pandas series return the element of my numpy datetime64 array as timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas Series which can be constructed like the following:

```
given_time = datetime(2013, 10, 8, 0, 0, 33, 945109, 
        tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=60, name=None))
given_times = np.array([given_time] * 3, dtype='datetime64[ns]'))
column = pd.Series(given_times)
```

The `dtype` of my Series is `datetime64[ns]`

However, when I access it: `column[1]`, somehow it becomes of type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`, while `column.values[1]` stays `np.datetime64`. Does Pandas auto cast my `datetime` into `Timestamp` when accessing the item? Is it slow?

Do I need to worry about the difference in types? As far as I see, `Timestamp` seems not have timezone (`numpy.datetime64('2013-10-08T00:00:33.945109000+0100') -> Timestamp('2013-10-07 23:00:33.945109', tz=None)`)

In practice, I would do `datetime` arithmetic like take difference, compare to a `datetimedelta`. Does the possible type inconsistency around my operators affect my use case at all?

Besides, am I encouraged to use `pd.to_datetime` instead of `astype(dtype='datetime64')` while converting datetime objects?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas time types are built on top of numpy's datetime64.

In order to continue using the pandas operators, you should keep using `pd.to_datetime`, rather than as `astype(dtype='datetime64')`. This is especially true since you'll be taking date time deltas, which pandas handles admirably, for example with resampling, and period definitions.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#period

Though I haven't measured, since the pandas times are hiding numpy times, I suspect the conversion, is quite fast. Alternatively, you can just use pandas built in time series definitions and avoid the conversion altogether.

As a rule of thumb, it's good to use the type from the package you'll be using functions from, though. So if you're really only going to use numpy to manipulate the arrays, then stick with numpy date time. Pandas methods => pandas date time.

Answer (score 0):

I had read in the documentation somewhere (apologies, can't find link) that scalar values will be converted to timestamps while arrays will keep their data type.  For example:

```
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
time_series = pd.Series([date(2010 + x, 1, 1) for x in range(5)])
time_series = time_series.apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

so that:

```
In[1]:time_series
Out[1]: 
0   2010-01-01
1   2011-01-01
2   2012-01-01
3   2013-01-01
4   2014-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

and yet:

```
In[2]:time_series.iloc[0]
Out[2]:Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00')
```

while:

```
In[3]:time_series.values[0]
In[3]:numpy.datetime64('2009-12-31T19:00:00.000000000-0500')
```

because iloc requests a scalar from pandas (type conversion to Timestamp) while values requests the full numpy array (no type conversion).

There is similar behavior for series of length one.  Additionally, referencing more than one element in the slice (ie iloc[1:10]) will return a series, which will always keep its datatype.

I'm unsure as to why pandas behaves this way.

```
In[4]: pd.__version__
Out[4]: '0.15.2'
```